# Difference in reading a file path that starts with single or double slash

Tags: iphone, c, linux

I recently had a application which does a recursive tree walk on the directories in the iPhone  file system. I realised that there are some directories which give me a different output when my path starts with `/` and `//`. For example :

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/<Unique String>/smth.txt
```

will give me **Not Readable** and **Not Writeable** while

```
//private/var/mobile/Applications/<Unique String>/smth.txt
```

will give me **Readable** and **Writable**.

Is there any difference with the single or double slash? I have read online and there should be no difference between the 2. However why am I getting different results. I am using access() calls to get the accessiblity of the files/directories.

```
//check read access
rval = access (path, R_OK);
 if (rval == 0)
  printf ("%s is readable\n", path);
 else
  printf ("%s is not readable (access denied)\n", path);

//check write access
 rval = access (path, W_OK);
 if (rval == 0)
  printf ("%s is writable\n", path);
 else 
  printf ("%s is not writable\n", path);
```

**Edit**
I realise that it will give me Not Readable and Not Writeable when there is an extra slash after my path such as

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/<Unique String>/smth.txt/
```

does an extra slash after the path makes a difference?

Comment: What happens when you add more slashes?

Comment: Well if I add a couple more slashes it will give me the same result as the double slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you realize this shouldn't happen (and probably isn't).  `access` can fail for other reasons than file permissions so the sensible first step is to change your code to display the error that is returned in `errno`.  There could be a simple explanation, for example, the extra slash put you over PATH_MAX or similar.

```
int rval;

//check read access
rval = access (path, R_OK);

if (rval == 0)
    printf ("%s is readable\n", path);
else
{
    perror("access read");
    printf ("%s is not readable (access denied)\n", path);
}

//check write access
rval = access (path, W_OK);

if (rval == 0)
    printf ("%s is writable\n", path);
else
{
    perror("access write");
    printf ("%s is not writable\n", path);
}
```